# Is proving an inequality like this correct?

Tags: inequality

I was told to prove, for n and p positive integers : ($n^p$) < ((n+1)^(p+1) - n^(p+1)) / (p+1).
So I proceeded like this:
I used the fact that $b^p$ - $a^p$ = (b - a)(b^(p-1) + (b^(p-2))a + (b^(p-3))(a^2) + ... + (ba^(p-2)) + a(p-1)) to tell that ((n+1)^(p+1) - n^(p+1)) = (n + 1 - n) ($(n+1)^p$ + ((n+1)^(p-1))n + ((n+1)^(p-2))$n^2$ + ... + $n^p$). Then I told that the inequality is the same as ($n^p$)p + ($n^p$) < ($(n+1)^p$ + ((n+1)^(p-1))n + ((n+1)^(p-2))$n^2$ + ... + $n^p$). The ($n^p$) on each side can be taken out because it is on both sides. For the rest I just told that the inequality holds because there are p terms on the right side (as the ($n^p$) has been taken out) and each of them has a ($n^p$) in their development due to the power of (n+1) time the power of n. Hence the right side can be rewritten as (($n^p$)p + A) where A is the sum of the terms of the right side aside from the $(n^p)$'s. A have to be positive as n and p are both positives. So the initial inequality holds.

Is trying to prove something in a way that is not entirely algebraic like that bad?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).